# get method returns undefined value although inside the method the value is not empty

Tags: json, angular, typescript, get

My method is

```
getOrganizations() : any[]{

this._http.get(this._url)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(
            data => { 
            console.log(data.responseData.org_list);
            return data.responseData.org_list;
            },
```

my json is

```
{"status":0,"statusMessage":"Success","responseData":{"org_list":[{"organizationName":"orgName1","summary":"org1Summary"}]},"errors":[]}


console.log(data.responseData.org_list);
```

prints out [Object]

but when i call this method from component like so:

```
constructor(private _service: OrganizationService){
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.organizations = this._service.getOrganizations();
    console.log(this._service.getOrganizations());
    console.log(this.organizations);    
    }
```

I get undefined in both console outputs

What could be the reasons of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refactor your method this way:

```
getOrganizations() : any[]{
  return this._http.get(this._url)
    .map(res => res.json())
    .map(data => data.responseData.org_list);
}
```

and call it this way:

```
constructor(private _service: OrganizationService){
}

ngOnInit(){
  this._service.getOrganizations()
    .subscribe(organizations => {
      this.organizations = organizations;
    });
}
```

Don't forget that observables are asynchronous and you can't return something directly...

Answer (score 0):

There is no `return` in your

```
getOrganizations() : any[]{
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to the async nature of http calls I'd propose this setup:

```
getOrganizations(): Observable {
    return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map(res => res.json().responseData.org_list);
}
```

And in your component just subscribe to your service method:

```
constructor(private _service: OrganizationService){
}

ngOnInit(){
    this._service.getOrganizations()
        .subscribe((data) => {
            this.organizations = data;
            console.log(this.organizations); 
        }
    );     
}
```